# Correctly accounting for multiple backslashes when tokenizing custom mini-format

Tags: python, regex, format, escaping, tokenize

I am writing a small tokenizer in Python for a custom mini-format which looks like this (it can be nested too):

```
<tag:some_text>
```

`tag` is a combination of a finite set of values and `some_text` is just text. The delimiters `<`, `:` and `>` can be escaped by a single `\` if they appear in, and as, text.

I used the regex `r"((\\)?[<:>])"` along with `re.finditer` to find delimiters and then remove the backslash if necessary by checking with `token.startswith('\\')`. The problem is that if more backslashes come before the delimiter, the regex is wrong, e.g. `"<tag:Some \\\\< text>" -> ['<', 'tag', ':', 'Some \\\\', '<', ' text', '>']`.

I cannot find a sensible solution using regexes, and I am considering just writing the tokenization in pure Python, i.e. no regex magic etc (but that may be slow?) or am I overcomplicating this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression will only match the last backslash and delimiter `\<` in `\\\\<`.

Just add the `+` quantifier which means (`1` or more times)

```
((\\+)?[<:>])
```

Comment: That will make it way easier to parse, thanks :). I worked on this all day, so I should have seen this before. I could call .count on that part of the match to figure out if I have to see the delimiter as a real one or an escaped one.